# Is there a term for Gojira's style?

Tags: metal, style

In case you don't know **Gojira**, [here's their latest album](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njgOZNaChEQ).

I think their style is really close (*if it's not totally it*) to **melodic death metal**, just like [Amon Amarth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjRUee5S44w) or [Dark Tranquility](https://youtu.be/kliQ417Isww) style's is but, at the same time, I see some similarities with **metalcore**, like [Breakdown of Sanity](https://youtu.be/e3jAnAqYhU4), for example, and **death core**(*less with this one*) like [Thy Art Is Murder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9EYD8dkxao).

Does anyone know if there's a term to refer to their *style* or is it just a mix of everything I mencioned?

Comment: Eventually, these pigeon-holes people are insistent on putting everything into will be so small, there will only be room for one pigeon in each.

Comment: I'm honestly not trying to. Music styles, *in my opinion*, are just a way of better finding songs you could enjoy and that's all, every band/musician is different and so is their style.

Comment: Since most of their songs start slow-paced & gradually unfold into an explosive kind of style, I think it's fair to tag them primarily with the genre, 'Progressive metal'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after quite some time, yes, Gojira is progressive death metal.

Source: youtube comments on their videos.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is 'One of the best bands of 21st century' but i guess it's safe to say they are a progressive metal band since they don't always go full on death metal and rely on lot of stuff such as groove and cannot be categorised into one single genre.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my two cents here-- *the* reference in all matters metal, namely the Metal Archives, describes [Gojira](https://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Gojira/18351) as *Progressive/Groove/Death Metal*, that is, a mix of prog metal, groove metal and death metal.

The nuance is subtle with *Progressive Groove/Death Metal*, where the music is groove/death metal that is progressive, not exactly the same.

The Metal Archives constitute the most reliable authority for heavy metal, and it has a very active community; it's a good idea to consult it for any related inquiry (I browse it quite often myself, either to discover new bands or contribute).

Comment: yeah, I agree that prog groove/death metal fits quite well for gojira